# Can't get this grid to align properly

Tags: java, layout, grid, javafx

I've been having trouble today with a grid that doesn't align the way i want.
How can i align it the way i want it too?

Example + code:

[image]

I want the part in the 3rd column i marked red to be gone and make it end at the end of my image.

```
    private GridPane login(final BorderPane rootLayout) {     
// Create a grid layout
        final GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 50));

// Set header text and add it to the grid
        Text sceneTitle = new Text("Welcome");
        sceneTitle.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma", FontWeight.NORMAL, 25));
        grid.add(sceneTitle, 0, 0, 2, 1);

// Create username label and textfield and add it to the grid
        Label labelUser = new Label("Username: ");
        grid.add(labelUser, 0, 1);
        TextField textUser = new TextField();
        grid.add(textUser, 1, 1);

// Create password label and field and add it to the grid
        Label labelPass = new Label("Password: ");
        grid.add(labelPass, 0, 2);
        PasswordField textPass = new PasswordField();
        grid.add(textPass, 1, 2);

// Create a button to login and add it to the grid
        Button buttonLogin = new Button("Login");
        HBox hbButton = new HBox(10);
        hbButton.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
        hbButton.getChildren().add(buttonLogin);
        grid.add(hbButton, 1, 4);        

// Create kone logo and add it to the bottom of the layout
        ImageView imageKone = new ImageView(
                new Image(MainWindow.class.getResourceAsStream("Resources/konecranes.png")));
        grid.add(imageKone, 0, 7, 3, 2);

// Create capman logo and add it to the top_right
        ImageView imageCapman = new ImageView(
                new Image(MainWindow.class.getResourceAsStream("Resources/Capman.png")));


// Login button actionHandler, make it do login and edit root layout.
        buttonLogin.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                grid.setGridLinesVisible(!grid.isGridLinesVisible());
            }
        });

        return grid;
    }
```

Thanks in advance,
Jasper.

Comment: I've been trying to add ColumConstraints before adding the nodes for 2 columns, and then setting the maxWidth per column this doesn't seem to affect the 2nd column tho and it's glitchy with the 1st column aswell. :-(

Comment: I was also curious about your question. Perhaps the following addresses can bring you some help: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/ColumnConstraints.html   http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/07/javafx-20-layout-panes-gridpane.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i've had sort of success using the 2nd link by reading up on the GridPane static methods. And so i did it using GridPane.setMargin(); Although it doesn't perfectly center my Grid this way but perhaps i can add a margin from outside aswell to push it to center.

Comment: If you have succeeded in doing the layout of your program, would it be too much to ask you to share your code with us? Maybe you could edit your question and add your final code. I really wonder how this could be done.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Loa i've had this worked out by using static GridPane methods and adding a Margin this way to certain nodes. Here's the link he/she shared:
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/07/javafx-20-layout-panes-gridpane.html

Although the grid is not perfectly centered now because of some whitespace in the 2nd column it might be able to center it with extra padding on the other side of the grid :-) I do not know if this is a correct way to solve the problem but it works for me :-P

Edit: Did indeed get it centered by adding the extra padding the opposite side of the nodes with margin.

Comment: Fun fact: I added another logo to (0,0) and than suddenly the 2nd column does perfectly stop at the end of the bottom image removing the need for margin and padding. I'm flabbergasted really :-P

Comment: Well, you-re welcome. Glad to have helped you. Good luck on your projects.